# How to combine this set of nginx directives into one regular expression rule

Tags: nginx, regex

I have these working directives:

```
     location /en/tools {
        alias /srv/nuxt/tools/dist/en/tools;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @cache;
     }
     location /ar/tools {
        alias /srv/nuxt/tools/dist/ar/tools;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @cache;
     }
     location /he/tools {
        alias /srv/nuxt/tools/dist/he/tools;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @cache;
     }
```

I have tried to combine them into one regex based directive but the server returns error 403:

```
location ~* ^/(en|ar|he)/tools/(.*) {
    alias /srv/nuxt/tools/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @cache;
}
```

Comment: Don't. Use the separate location directives.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `alias` for any of your `location` blocks. Use `root /srv/nuxt/tools/dist;`. Nginx processes *prefix* locations very efficiently. *regular expressions* need to be evaluated individually by a separate library.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, would you kindly explain why is that better than using one regex based directive?

Comment: @RichardSmith, you mean that using ` location /en/tools {..}` is faster than using regex?

Comment: In general, yes. So if maximum performance is a design goal, the number of regular expressions should be minimised.

Comment: @RichardSmith beat me to it. Yes, performance is the concern here. If you have any regex locations, then every request has to be checked against them using a regex match, in addition to the hash table lookup that the other locations use. It's usually a small difference but as your site grows the difference will grow as well. There are times you can't avoid a regex location, but this isn't one of them. See [How nginx processes a request](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for all the gory details.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I have done some bench-marking between two sites downloading same image file. First with no regex definitions at all, the second with some regex based rules The difference for 5000 requests at the rate 300/s is merely: 0.013 ms.